# XSLT Rearrange or Regroup Nodes Efficiently

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to rearrange a set of XML nodes for further processing.
The basic idea is that I need to change the grouping of my nodes using efficient XSLT processing.

The input structure I have is:

```
<all_nodes>
  <student>
    <math>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </math>
    <science>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </science>
    <history>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </history>
  </student>
  <student>
    <math>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </math>
    <science>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </science>
    <history>
      <record>
        <detail1/>
        <detail2/>
      </record>
    </history>
  </student>
</all_nodes>
```

The desired output is grouped by subjects instead.
Note that the `student` node is dropped as it will not be needed
I just need the `record` nodes with common subject parent node grouped together:

```
<all_nodes>
  <math>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
  </math>
  <science>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
  </science>
  <history>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
    <record>
      <detail1/>
      <detail2/>
    </record>
  </history>
</all_nodes>
```

I was able to achieve the desired output by using the following code, however I think there may be a better approach to this.
Can you advise on how I can improve the code?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="math"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="science"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="history"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="math">
    <xsl:element name="math">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//math/record" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="science">
    <xsl:element name="science">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//science/record" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="history">
    <xsl:element name="history">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//history/record" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: First comment - you don't need to use `<xsl:element name="xyz">` when the name is fixed, just use a literal `<xyz>` instead.

Comment: Is "math, science and history" an exhaustive list?

Comment: I'm using XSLT version 2.0.
The current assumption is that I may have an indefinite number of subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more generic implementation using **XSLT 2.0** that would support any subject without explicitly enumerating them in the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>            
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*/*" group-by="local-name(..)">
                <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works, thank you!
However, should I be concerned with the wildcards regarding performance ? The code may have to process thousands of student nodes.

Comment: No, performance should not be impacted, but you could try specifying the element names and compare execution times to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If it's **always** just the three known subjects, then you could do this quite simply as:

```
[deleted]
```

***Edit: actually, using a key is not likely to bring a significant advantage here, so why not just make it even simpler:***

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/all_nodes">
    <xsl:copy>
        <math>
            <xsl:copy-of select="student/math/record"/>
        </math>
        <science>
            <xsl:copy-of select="student/science/record"/>
        </science>
        <history>
            <xsl:copy-of select="student/history/record"/>
        </history>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Right now there are a couple number of subjects but I need to be on the safe side and assume some may be added or removed in the future -- which is also the flaw in my current code.

Comment: Well, then Mads Hansen gave you the answer for XSLT 2.0, and you will find the answer for XSLT 1.0 here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html